# css is blank when there are multiple lines

Tags: css, asp.net

This article is translated by Google Translator, so please understand the grammar.

I am currently creating a page with asp. But yesterday I can not load the css link that worked well.
css will load when there are only a few lines but if there are many lines, it will be blank.
Is there a workaround for this error?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8JKa.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05Sj6.jpg)

Comment: can you share the code or show any the error in console if any.

Comment: There is no error on the console. When I click the css link in the page source view, only a blank screen is displayed.

Comment: May be you missed to close some brackets,  do a line by line debug

Comment: Other css files in the same path will be loaded. Certain css files do not load.

Comment: If the code in css file is 1 ~ 2 lines, it will be loaded, but if there are many lines, it will not load. Could this be the result of a server problem?

Comment: no, can you add a screenshot of blank pages source code, and the css

Comment: Domains cannot be made public for security reasons.
However, as you can see in the screenshot, when I click the link in the page source view, no code is displayed.

Comment: Try  clearing the cache and restart app

Comment: If you clear your cache, reconnect FTP, and reboot your computer, the results are the same.